# JS local storage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having this problem with a alert box that I have made to show up every time you navigate my slideshow using the controls that states "Slideshow auto advance has stopped"
So I am wondering is there a way to make like a cookie or anything to store information locally so that if they press the control once and see the message it would stop displaying if they keep navigating.

*JS Script*

```
<script>
        $(document).ready( function() {

                $("#pressed1").click( function() {
                    jConfirm('Slideshow auto advance has stopped!<br />Press OK to stop showing this message for 2 hour.', 'Website alert');
                });

            });

        $(document).ready( function() {

                $("#pressed2").click( function() {
                    jConfirm('Slideshow auto advance has stopped!<br />Press OK to stop showing this message for 2 hour.', 'Website alert');
                });

            });

        $(document).ready( function() {

                $("#pressed3").click( function() {
                    jConfirm('Slideshow auto advance has stopped!<br />Press OK to stop showing this message for 2 hour.', 'Website alert');
                });

            });

        $(document).ready( function() {

                $("#pressed4").click( function() {
                    jConfirm('Slideshow auto advance has stopped!<br />Press OK to stop showing this message for 2 hour.', 'Website alert');
                });

            });
</script>
```

HTML Code

```
<div id="main2">  
  <div id="gallery">

    <div id="slides">
    <div class="slide"><img src="imgs/slide.imgs/1.jpg" onmousedown="return false;" style="border-style: none" width="1040" height="400" alt="side" /></div>
    <div class="slide"><img src="imgs/slide.imgs/1.jpg" onmousedown="return false;" style="border-style: none" width="1040" height="400" alt="side" /></div>
    <div class="slide"><img src="imgs/slide.imgs/3.gif" onmousedown="return false;" style="border-style: none" width="1040" height="400" alt="side" /></div>
    <div class="slide"><a href="buywebdesign.html" onmousedown="return false;" target="_blank"><img src="imgs/slide.imgs/4.gif" style="border-style: none" width="1040" height="400" alt="side" /></a></div>
    </div>

    <div id="menu">
    <ul><div class="thumbs">
        <li class="fbar">&nbsp;</li>
        <li class="menuItem"><a href=""><img src="imgs/slide.imgs/thumb_ball.png" id="pressed1" onmousedown="return false;" style="border-style: none" alt="thumbnail" /></a></li>
        <li class="menuItem"><a href=""><img src="imgs/slide.imgs/thumb_ball.png" id="pressed2" onmousedown="return false;" style="border-style: none" alt="thumbnail" /></a></li>
        <li class="menuItem"><a href=""><img src="imgs/slide.imgs/thumb_ball.png" id="pressed3" onmousedown="return false;" style="border-style: none" alt="thumbnail" /></a></li>
        <li class="menuItem"><a href=""><img src="imgs/slide.imgs/thumb_ball.png" id="pressed4" onmousedown="return false;" style="border-style: none" alt="thumbnail" /></a></li>
   </div> </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont really understand your specific requirement but here's a shot in the air..

You can use window.localStorage ( object that will be retained by the browser for your website irrespective of page reloads )

You can set a flag like

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    window.localStorage['messaged_displayed'] = false;
});
```

for the first reload..
and whenever you want to display the message just do

```
if(!window.localStorage['messaged_displayed']) {
    jConfirm('Slideshow auto advance has stopped!<br />Press OK to stop showing this message for 2 hour.', 'Website alert');
    window.localStorage['messaged_displayed'] = true;
}
```

then again reset the flag to false after 2 hours.

if you dont know how to implement this then,
I'd like to edit Dylan Hayes's example

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var msg = "Slideshow auto advance has stopped!<br />Press OK to stop showing this message for 2 hour.";

    $("#pressed1, #pressed2, #pressed3, #pressed4, #pressed5 ").click(function () {
        rightNow = new Date()
        if (window.localStorage['lastClicked'])
        {
            if (rightNow - window.localStorage['lastClicked'] > 7200000) { // milliseconds of 2 hrs
                jConfirm(msg, 'Website alert');
                window.localStorage['lastClicked'] = rightNow
            }
        }
        else {
            window.localStorage['lastClicked'] = rightNow
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: assuming you understood what Dylan Hayes wrote, i am extending his answer for explanation @MauritzN

Comment: Problem!
The alert box wont display at all now
Tried it on diffrent computers and have tried diffrent browsers

Comment: there must be something wrong either in your code or the browser isnt HTML5 compatible

Comment: so its working in one browser and not on the other?
Do note that localStorage variable is stored by the browser so anyother browser wouldnt know about it... u will have to make use of server if you want some global support for your situation

Answer (score 0):

Actually I think there are probably a number of things you could do here.

You really only need the 1 document.ready, and you can have more than one element in your selector statement.

For your specific problem I would just set a boolean that starts as true, will display once, and then once the message is displayed it will set to false and no longer make it into the if() statement.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var msg = "Slideshow auto advance has stopped!<br />Press OK to stop showing this message for 2 hour.";
        var displayAlert = true;

        $("#pressed1, #pressed2, #pressed3, #pressed4, #pressed5 ").click(function () {
            if (displayAlert) {
                jConfirm(msg, 'Website alert');
                displayAlert = false;
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: It seems to work, but when you reload the page it gets reset. I would like it to last for 2 hours and then it would reset.